# Swift dictionary sorting

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

just wondered how dictionary sorts in Swift. e.g. the following code.

```
var occupations = [
"Malcolm": "Captain",
"Kaylee": "Mechanic"]

occupations["Jayne"] = "Pirate"

for (name, occupation) in occupations{
print("\(name) is a \(occupation)")
}
```

The outcome looks like this

```
Kaylee is a Mechanic 
Malcolm is a Captain
Jayne is a Pirate
```

My question stands. How does the cycle decide which name(or a key) will be first passed through the above cycle?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113: *"A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in a collection with **no defined ordering**."*

Comment: Have a read up on hash tables, which is what Swift's `Dictionary` uses in order to store elements. An element's position in the table primarily depends on its hash and the number of buckets in the table, and secondarily on how the hash table handles collisions.

Comment: If you're just curious that's fine, but remember you should never write code that depends on the order in a dictionary. As it as no defined ordering, they have every right to change the ordering between versions of the OS/language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple [Collection Types Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html):

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and
>   values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering. Each
>   value is associated with a unique key, which acts as an identifier for
>   that value within the dictionary. **Unlike items in an array, items in a**
>   **dictionary do *not* have a specified order**.

By default, dictionary data structure has unspecified ordering, means that each time you will iterate through it you might have a different sorting. However you can sort based on the *keys* or the *values* of it, both of them are represented as arrays.

So, let's say that you want to sort based on the keys:

```
    var occupations = [
    "Malcolm": "Captain",
    "Kaylee": "Mechanic"]

occupations["Jayne"] = "Pirate"

for key in occupations.keys.sort() {
    print("KEY: \(key) VALUE: \(occupations[key])")
}
```

Console should shows -sorted based on the key-:

> **KEY**: Jayne **VALUE**: Optional("Pirate")
>
> **KEY**: Kaylee **VALUE**: Optional("Mechanic")
>
> **KEY**: Malcolm **VALUE**: Optional("Captain")

*Note that the values are optionals, you may need to "optional binding" them...*

Hope this helped.

Comment: Having an unspecified ordering is not the same as unordered – the dictionary has an order (it's just unspecified), therefore repeatedly iterating over a given dictionary will not yield different orderings of elements – you'll get the same elements in the same order. However, adding or removing elements *can* change this order (again, how the order is changed is unspecified).

Comment: @Hamish thanks for the note, answer has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
    var occupations = [
        "Malcolm": "Captain",
        "Kaylee": "Mechanic"]

    occupations["Jayne"] = "Pirate"

    let unsortedKeys = occupations.keys //get dictionary keys
    let sortedKeys = unsortedKeys.sorted(by: <) //sort dictionary keys
    for key in sortedKeys {
        print("\(key) is a \(occupations[key])")
    }
```

Hope that helps