# convert [(key: String, value: String)] in [String:String]

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want convert [(key: String, value: String)] in [String:String] is possible to do ? If yes how i make ? thanks

```
var KeyValuePair: [(key: String, value: String)] = [(key: "2017 01 04", value: "143.65"), (key: "2017 01 05", value: "140.78"), (key: "2017 01 06", value: "150.23")]
```

in

```
var dictionary: [String:String] =  ["2017 01 04":"143.65", "2017 01 05":"140.78", "2017 01 06":"150.23"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to iterate through the array of tuples and set the key-value pair of your dictionary with the values of the tuple.

```
var keyValuePairs: [(key: String, value: String)] = [(key: "2017 01 04", value: "143.65"), (key: "2017 01 05", value: "140.78"), (key: "2017 01 06", value: "150.23")]

var dictionary = [String:String]()
keyValuePairs.forEach{
    dictionary[$0.0] = $0.1
    //since you have named tuples, you could also write dictionary[$0.key] = $0.value
}
print(dictionary)
```

Please make sure you conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelcase for variable names.

Comment: To be clear: this code handles key collisions by simply taking the last value for any key.

Comment: but, the order is unsorted.

Comment: @MuraliDharanV yes, `Dictionary` is unsorted by definition. If you need a sorted data type, you need to keep your data as an `Array`.

Comment: But things getting me start from first. [String:String] = [“1”:”A”,”3”:”C”,”2”:”B”] need to be sorted as [String:String] = [“1”:”A”,”2”:”B”,”3”:”C”]. Can refer any link for the exact requirement

Comment: @MuraliDharanV as I've said, that's not possible. `Dictionary` is unordered by definition, you cannot have a sorted `Dictionary`. You can have a sorted array of key-value pair tuples, but cannot have a sorted `Dictionary`. See [Swift Dictionary Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366293/swift-dictionary-sorting)

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor:  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

## Swift 4:

If you are sure the the keys are unique, you can use [`Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init):

```
let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: keyValuePairs)
```

Otherwise, you can use [`Dictionary.init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2892961-init) instead, which allows you to specify how to handle collisions.

```swift
let dict = Dictionary(keyValuePairs, uniquingKeysWith: { previous, new in
    return new //always takes the newest value for a given key
})
```

Comment: my keys are unique, my array is of type [String:String] = ["1":"Albaman","3":"Mexico","2":"Los Vegas"], i am trying to sort using myarray..sorted(by: {$0.value < $1.value}) and got the result in keyvalue pairs and when i try to convert that to [String:String], again it was in unsorted data.

Comment: Please post a new question. But first, search for existing answers for your problem. You’ll find hundreds of answers explaining that dictionaries have no defined ordering, and that a “sorted dictionary” doesn’t exist without leveraging a third party ordered dictionary implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The one line functional approach would be:

```
let dictionary = keyValuePair.reduce([String : String]())
                 {  acc, item in
                    var output = acc
                    output.updateValue(item.value, forKey: item.key)
                    return output
                 }
```

You could also neaten things up by implementing an `extension` to `Dictionary`

```
extension Dictionary
{
    func appending(value: Value, key: Key) -> Dictionary
    {
        var mutable = self
        mutable.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        return mutable
    }
}

let dictionary = keyValuePair.reduce([String : String]()) { $0.appending(value: $1.value, key: $1.key) }
```