# Initializing a Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:) from KeyValuePairs

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift5

```
struct Data {
    let storage: [String: Int]
    
    init(_ pairs: KeyValuePairs<String, Int>) {
        storage = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: pairs)
    }
}
```

Compilation error:

> Initializer 'init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)' requires the types
> 'KeyValuePairs<String, Int>.Element' (aka '(key: String, value: Int)')
> and '(String, Int)' be equivalent

What can be more natural than to initialize Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:) with KeyValuePairs!? It's just ridiculous that it's impossible to do straightforwardly!
`requires '(key: String, value: Int)' and '(String, Int)' be equivalent` they are equivalent!

Comment: `storage = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: Array(pairs))`  should do the trick. `KeyValuePair` isn't a sequence, it's `public init<S>(uniqueKeysWithValues keysAndValues: S) where S : Sequence, S.Element == (Key, Value)` after all.

Comment: @Larme Yes, that works. I'm going to dig in documentation in order to understand your explanation, but your code compiles and works as expected. Can you please make a post, I will be able to except it as an answer then :)

Comment: @Larme The type is not `KeyValuePair`, it's `KeysValue*PAIRS*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because [KeyValuePairs.Element](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs/element) has labels.

```swift
type(of: (key: "", value: 0)) == type(of: ("", 0)) // false
```

You need another overload or just an in-place removal of the labels.

```swift
public extension Dictionary {
  /// Creates a new dictionary from the key-value pairs in the given sequence.
  ///
  /// - Parameter keysAndValues: A sequence of key-value pairs to use for
  ///   the new dictionary. Every key in `keysAndValues` must be unique.
  /// - Returns: A new dictionary initialized with the elements of
  ///   `keysAndValues`.
  /// - Precondition: The sequence must not have duplicate keys.
  @inlinable init<Elements: Sequence>(uniqueKeysWithValues keysAndValues: Elements)
  where Elements.Element == Element {
    self.init(
      uniqueKeysWithValues: keysAndValues.map { ($0, $1) }
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(
  Dictionary(
    uniqueKeysWithValues: ["": "", "‍♀️": "‍♂️"] as KeyValuePairs
  ),
  .init(
    uniqueKeysWithValues: [("", ""), ("‍♀️", "‍♂️")]
  )
)
```

Comment: This is does not handle duplicate values. It will fail on `Data(["a": 1, "b": 2, "a": 3] as KeyValuePairs)` with *Fatal error: Duplicate values for key: 'a'*

Comment: Yes, see the precondition. The other overload for dealing with this was also introduced in Swift 4.

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift is not supporting **Splatting** (yet), this is how you can achieve it:

```
struct Data {
    let storage: [String: Int]

    init(_ pairs: KeyValuePairs<String, Int>) {
        storage = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: pairs.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 } .map { $0 })
    }
}
```

Usages:

```
let data = Data(KeyValuePairs(dictionaryLiteral: ("a", 1), ("b", 2)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also use `reduce`:

```
storage = pairs.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value }
```

This will work even if you have duplicate keys in `pairs` (currently it takes the last item from duplicates:

```
let data = Data(["a": 1, "b": 2, "a": 3] as KeyValuePairs)
print(data.storage) 
// ["a": 3, "b": 2]
```

---

If you need it to take the first item you can do:

```
storage = pairs.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { $0[$1.key] = $0[$1.key] ?? $1.value }
```

(or shorter)

```
storage = pairs.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { $0[$1.0] = $0[$1.0] ?? $1.1 }
```

This prints:

```
let data = Data(["a": 1, "b": 2, "a": 3] as KeyValuePairs)
print(data.storage) 
// ["a": 1, "b": 2]
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/dictionary-merging-function-with-default-uniquingkeys/39796

Answer (score -1):

• Fix:

```
storage = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: Array(pairs))
```

• Why:
The method you are trying to use is:

```
public init<S>(uniqueKeysWithValues keysAndValues: S) where S : Sequence, S.Element == (Key, Value)
```

And it's missing the `S.Element == (Key, Value)` compliance.

• A little further:
Note that if you have duplicate keys, you'll have an error. You can use then:

```
storage = Dictionary(Array(paris)) { _, new in
    return new //if you want to keep the last "key" value, or the reverse
}
```

• Other possibilities :
[convert [(key: String, value: String)] in [String:String]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984858/convert-key-string-value-string-in-stringstring)