# Swift: convert [Dictionary<String, [String : Double]>.Element] to [String : [String : Double]]

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have this JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "name": "first_category",
        "model": {
            "OK": 0.49404761904761907,
            "NOPE": 0.48214285714285715
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "second_category",
        "model": {
            "YOP": 0.389338593,
            "GO": 0.20420894
        }
    }
]
```

I have created this struct to decode it:

```
struct JSONModel: Codable {
    let name: String
    let model: [String: Double]
}
```

The decoding:

```
let decodedModel = try? decoder.decode([JSONModel].self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
```

It correctly fills the array as expected, but now I would like to use this array to create a dictionary whose keys would be the `JSONModel` names, and values the models. This is what I expect to get:

```
[
    "first_category": [
        "OK": 0.49404761904761907, 
        "NOPE": 0.4821428571428571
    ],
    "second_category": [
        "YOP": 0.389338593, 
        "GO": 0.20420894
    ]
]
```

So I tried this:

```
let simplifiedModel: [String: [String: Double]] = decodedModel.flatMap { [$0.name: $0.model] }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Dictionary<String, [String : Double]>.Element]' to closure result type '[String : [String : Double]]'

What should I do instead?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What happens if you remove type ``` [String: [String: Double]]``` for simplifiedModel.

Comment: @RajaKishan Yes this works, but I would like to have it as a `[String: [String: Double]]`

Comment: You cannot `(flat)Map` an array to a dictionary. the result of `flatMap` is an **array** of tuples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45985125/14733292

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `reduce(into:)` for this

```
let dictionary = decodedModel.reduce(into: [:]) { 
    $0[$1.name] = $1.model
}
```

Comment: `default: [String: Double]()` isn't needed since `model` isn't optional, no?